# htaccess redirect with variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, redirect

I realise there are similar questions but I'm trying to work out how I can rewrite the following URL:

```
http://www.myWEBaddress.com/?month=200904
```

to

```
http://www.myWEBaddress.com/my-page.php?month=200904
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)month= [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ my-page.php [L]
```

If you want to change the URL that the user sees in their browser address bar, change the last rule to

```
RewriteRule ^ my-page.php [L,R=301]
```