# .htaccess redirect based on url value

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url as below.

```
http://example.com/listing?listingid=237508&2000
```

What I want is to redirect it to a mobile version of the site.

```
http://example.com/mobile-listing?listingid=237508&2000
```

The problem is that if it is **example.com/listing** it should redirect to **example.com/mobile-listing**.  If it is **example.com/event** it should redirect to **example.com/mobile-event** and so on. How am I to do this? I have seen question about redirection to mobile version based on url parameters or getvalue. But not this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i've found a simuluar answer from *ulrich palha* which might helps.
[question id 9113747](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113747/htaccess-redirect-with-variables)
in the .htaccess file of root you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)listingid= [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ mobile-listing [L,R=301]
```

hopes this helps. you might change a little and this should point in the right direction to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`RewriteRule` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and `QSA` and `PT` flags

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/listing$ /mobile-listing [PT,QSA] 
    …
</VirtualHost>
```

### Flags

- [`PT`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt):

> Forces the resulting URI to be passed back to the URL mapping engine
>   for processing of other URI-to-filename translators, such as Alias or
>   Redirect. details ...

- [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

> Appends any query string from the original request URL to any query
>   string created in the rewrite target.details

### More information

You can find more scenarios at [Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

Without any sort of condition for what is mobile or what isn't, and you *always* redirect, then the rule would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile-
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /mobile-$1 [L,R]
```

The query string will automatically get appended. Change the `R` to `R=301` if you want to permanently redirect.